# Arrow with jquery between table elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to draw an arrow between a selected cell of the right and the left table. The arrow is shifted upwards and I dont know why. I guess it is caused by a wrong calculation of the top offset (start and end?) but on my own I cant figure out how to calculate it properly in my `drawCurve` function

```js
$(function () {
  onload();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
  updateCurve();
});

function drawCurve(startElem, endElem) {
  var startOffsetParent = startElem.offsetParent();
  var endOffsetParent = endElem.offsetParent();

  var startOffset = startElem.offset();
  var endOffset = endElem.offset();

  var startWidth = startElem.outerWidth();
  var startHeight = startElem.outerHeight();
  var endWidth = endElem.outerWidth();
  var endHeight = endElem.outerHeight();

  var startX = startOffset.left + startWidth - startOffsetParent.offset().left;
  var startY =
    startOffset.top + startHeight / 2 - startOffsetParent.offset().top;
  var endX = endOffset.left - endOffsetParent.offset().left;
  var endY = endOffset.top + endHeight / 2 - endOffsetParent.offset().top;

  var curvePath =
    "M" +
    startX +
    "," +
    startY +
    " Q" +
    (startX + endX) / 2 +
    "," +
    startY +
    " " +
    endX +
    "," +
    endY;
  return curvePath;
}

function updateCurve() {
  var $active1 = $("#table1 .active");
  var $active2 = $("#table2 .active");

  if (
    $active1.length === 0 ||
    $active2.length === 0 ||
    $active1.text() === $active2.text()
  ) {
    $(".arrow").hide();
    return;
  }

  var startElem = $active1;
  var endElem = $active2;
  var curvePath = drawCurve(startElem, endElem);
  $("#curve").attr("d", curvePath);
  $(".arrow").show();
}

function selectAccount(event) {
  var $target = $(event.target).closest("tr");
  var $table = $target.closest("table");

  if ($target.hasClass("active") || $target.text() === "") {
    $("body").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("body").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    }, 500);
    return;
  }

  if ($table.find(".active").length >= 1) {
    var $activeRow = $table.find(".active");
    $activeRow.removeClass("active");
  }

  if ($(".active").length > 0 && $(".active").text() === $target.text()) {
    $("body").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("body").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    }, 500);
    return;
  }

  var number = 0; // sessionStorage.getItem("number");
  number = parseInt(number) + 1;
  //  sessionStorage.setItem("number", number);
  $target.addClass("active");
  if (number >= 2) {
    updateCurve();
  }
}

function generateTables(accounts) {
  var table1 = $("#table1");
  var table2 = $("#table2");

  for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
    var account = accounts[i];

    var row1 = $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text(account));
    var row2 = $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text(account));

    table1.append(row1);
    table2.append(row2);
  }
}

function onload() {
  //  sessionStorage.setItem("number", 0);
  var accounts = ["Konto 1", "Konto 2", "Konto 3", "Konto 4"];
  generateTables(accounts);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.tables-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  gap: 90px;
}

.table1 tr,
.table2 tr {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

.table1 tr.active,
.table2 tr.active {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.arrow {
  display: initial;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Ändere den z-index auf 1, um den Pfeil im Vordergrund zu positionieren */
}

.input-container {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.input-container input {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.button-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.error-message {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="back-button" onclick="window.location.href='mainpage.html'">
  <span class="triangle"></span>
  <span class="logout-text">Zurück</span>
</a>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <form>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Betrag" id="betrag" name="betrag" required>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="tables-container">
    <div>
      <a>von</a>
      <table id="table1" class="table1" onclick="selectAccount(event)"></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a>nach</a>
      <table id="table2" class="table2" onclick="selectAccount(event)"></table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <svg class="arrow" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <marker id="arrowhead" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="7" refX="0" refY="3.5" orient="auto">
        <polygon points="0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" />
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <path id="curve" fill="none" stroke="black" marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" />
  </svg>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button type="submit">Bestätigen</button>
  </div>
  <p class="error-message" id="error-message"></p>
</div>
```

The whole code can be seen [here](https://github.com/DDidas/private/blob/a4e1609fc00a3caaa94a489b853553634ae03d94/index.html), SO prohibited me to post it here.

Comment: I made you a snippet from the link. It is just the session storage part that does not work here. Please update the snippet to be a [mcve]

Comment: Also as a jsfiddle (taken from the snippet so localstorage code still commented):  runs, but no idea what it's supposed to do: https://jsfiddle.net/qetz0j3L/  **Edit** have to resize the window to get the "arrow" to appear

Comment: @freedomn-n I had the problem with the resize as well, but was able to workaround it with the session storage, idk why, but to appear the update is needed. So the selectAccount function updates the arrow, if two cells are chosen. If i would do it alwys, there would be a buggy as hell arrow, when only one cell is selected. but still, I dont know, why it is shifted that much.

Comment: Maybe try without display:flex, at least to get it working in the first instance.